# Most valuable StackTrace is lost when using Completer

Tags: dart

See example below:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

Future<void> main(List<String> arguments) async {
  try {
    await someMethod();
  } catch (e, st) {
    print("error: ${e}");
    print("st   : ${st}");
  }
}

Future<void> someMethod() async {
  final completer = Completer.sync();
  _scheduleCompletion(completer);
  await completer.future;
}

Future<void> _scheduleCompletion(Completer completer) async {
  Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1), () {
    try {
      [][0]; // simulating error
      completer.complete();
    } catch (e, st) {
      completer.completeError("error occured", st);
    }
  });
}
```

I am receiving following output:

```
#0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:254:60)
#1      _scheduleCompletion.<anonymous closure> (file:///home/work/stuff/projects/dart-async-exceptions/bin/dart_async_exceptions.dart:26:9)
#2      new Future.delayed.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:315:39)
#3      Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:18:15)
#4      _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:395:19)
#5      _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:426:5)
#6      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)
```

As you can see stacktrace does not allow you to see what steps led to error. What I expect is something like:

```
[anonymous closure, where error actually happens]
[someMethod]
[main]
```

while instead I see only last part.

I know there is package, called [stack_trace](https://pub.dev/packages/stack_trace), that allows you to "wrap your whole program in Chain.capture and you will be happy". Unfortunately my real-world case is not that simple and I can not simply "wrap my program" in "Chain.capture".
Another reason on not using "Chain.capture" thing is that in some cases it's onError handler gets even worse stacktrace vs. simple try/catch block .

Also I would like to understand why this is happening and what should I do to fix my program so part of valuable trace is not lost.

**UPDATE (based on Irn's answer):**

Let's re-write someMethod not to use completer, but rather call another async method:

```dart
Future<void> someMethod() async {
  await someOtherMethod();
}

Future<void> someOtherMethod() async {
  throw "another error";
}
```

In that case I will have following trace:

```
#0      someOtherMethod (file:///home/work/stuff/projects/dart-async-exceptions/bin/dart_async_exceptions_original.dart:24:3)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      someMethod (file:///home/work/stuff/projects/dart-async-exceptions/bin/dart_async_exceptions_original.dart:19:3)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      main (file:///home/work/stuff/projects/dart-async-exceptions/bin/dart_async_exceptions_original.dart:5:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

As you see it contains all invocations main -> someMethod -> someOtherMethod, that allows you to narrow down the issue. As I understand in that case we should also lose everything as we are scheduling calls on event loop. But we see everything works as expected. Why is that?

**About stack_trace package**: I would love to use it, but I made small experiment and looks like sometimes it provides worse trace then the one from try/catch. But that is topic for another question ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't trace a stack which doesn't exist.

Dart's asynchronous code is event loop based.
When you do `await someFuture`, your function really sets up a callback on that future, using [`Future.then`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.0/dart-async/Future/then.html), and then it *returns*. That unwinds the stack leading up to setting that callback, and eventually the stack all the way back to the event loop.
(The return only happens when you evaluate the `await`, the `someFuture` expression is invoked immediately, and if that manages to throw before doing something asynchronous, then you will get the stack trace containing the stack prior to the `await` returning).

At a later time, the event loop triggers and calls the callback, and the asynchronous computation continues from there.

The original stack no longer exists at that point, which is why you see a stack trace leading back to an event loop event (here, a timer, which the VM implements by sending port events at specific times). The stack you see is the only stack which exists at the point you ask for it.

You can use [`package:stack_trace`](https://pub.dev/packages/stack_trace) to capture a stack trace at the point where you schedule a callback, and then the stack trace package will remember that stack trace until the callback is run, and attempt to combine it with the stack traces reported (or captured) during the callback.
Since you make lots of callbacks, but don't usually need to see that many stack traces, it has a significant performance impact to capture stacks at every callback.

Comment: @Irn, thanks a lot for answering, but I am still have questions to be answered if possible. I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @Irn. I would like to go back to completer case. I was assuming that "await completer.future" would throw error after completer completed with error. In that case it would be possible to "combine" trace from completer and the one that happened at the moment when we started awaiting for completer.future ?

Comment: The *throw* happens synchronously, and the original stack trace is recorded when the throw happens. The error and stack trace are then used to complete the returned future "a little later", and then, eventually, the `await` responds to the future completing and re-raises the error and stack-trace from the future. 

The `stack_trace` package should (I think, I haven't actually used it myself) capture the 
stack trace at the point of the `await` and then combine it with the trace that is introduced at the `throw`. I don't know exactly how, or whether they can recognize the overlap here.

Comment: Allright, at first, my issue was with stack_trace package was not working correct, so I refused it and decided to rely on "native" try/catch approach. From the answer it is obvious that without stack_trace I can not handle "completer" (+ maybe some other more tricky cases). I looked more carefully at stack_trace's issues list and found this: https://github.com/dart-lang/stack_trace/issues/111, which leads to this: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/46326. So looks like once those issues are fixed stack_trace approach would be the way for me to proceed. Appreciate your input. Closing this.